# User Interface Markup Language (UIML) render to html

Tags: html, user-interface, xslt, renderer

I am currently investigating user interface (UI) generation through some meta-languages such as UIML. The language seems to be well standardized and it is one of the pioneers in that sense. (Here is a list of some other similar languages http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface_markup_language).

There are several UIML implementations - one particular in .NET and one in Java that I am aware of (also they are publicly available for download). **But** I am looking for a way to bring UIML to a browser and possibly combine it with XForms (which would be a good complement to UIML). The questions is, has someone had some experience with something similar? Are you aware if such project exists?

Through some papers, I read that a company called Harmonia used to have a UIML to HTML renderer, but apparently not anymore. Besides the official website of UIML is down (www.uiml.org), and one can find information only on the OASIS committee's website (https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/28457/uiml-4.0-cd01.pdf).

Correct me if wrong, but I guess these are the only approaches:

1. XSL transformation on the UIML document to a XHTML (possibly with XForms). Although, I feel that this approach is not the sort of 'native' way to UIML (due to it's vocabulary abstraction).
2. Implementing my own UIML to HTML renderer in a language of choice with it's specific vocabulary and a 'transformation engine' to output a html file in the end.

Hopefully, someone did some work/research in that direction. Would really appreciate any comments/guides/advises/experiences/etc.! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options:

- PyUIML, which is using the second approach listed in the question
- KUIMLRenderer, which natively parses UIML for QtWebkit browsers such as [QUPZilla](http://blog.qupzilla.com/)
- Android-UIML, a UIML renderer for Android
- Harmonia LiquidWeb, which uses desktop UIML to render HTML

**References**

- [PyUIML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyuiml/)
- [uiml.net](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jozilla/uiml.net/uiml.net-dev/files)
- [KUIMLRenderer](http://kuimlrenderer.sourceforge.net/)
- [Android-UIML](https://code.google.com/p/android-uiml/)
- [Harmonia LiquidWeb](http://liquidweb.harmonia.com/features/)

Comment: Thanks for your input! I had not seen PyUIML, but I will have a look at it later today. The KUIMLRenderer and the Android-UIML do not seem to be what I am looking for, but it's nice to know about them. As of Harmonia's LiquidWeb - I've requested registration a couple of times and there is no reply/nothing. I've tried the LiquidApps "IDE", but that's also out of my scope.

Comment: Happy to help, and remember to click the checkbox icon and up arrow next to the answer since it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We have augmented UIML and developed a Java based renderer that has been in use for quite some time (6-7 years). In fact, we also thought of providing
some sort of "Forms" support have plans of doing it with by adding a special
class "Form" with semantics generally expected from Forms:

```
<part id = "Login Form" class = "FORM" ...>
<part id = "User Id" class = "Text Field" ..>
```

....